# Is there scholarship on the history of Tarka sastra in North India?

Tags: history

Specifically, I am interested in the history of pūrvapakṣa approach during the period beginning from 1000 CE to 2000 CE in North India.

Comment: "Scholarship on the history" What does that mean?

Comment: The subject in the question is 'history of Tarka sastra' and by scholarship of this, i mean publications/works on the topic which are peer-reviewed and accepted by both the academic scholars as well as the practitioners of Tarka sastra.

Comment: May be more suitable on History.SE?